# Routing an Angular 2 app with Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, url-routing, angular-cli, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an Angular 2 application created with Angular CLI. This has to call a .NET 4.6 Web API. The route setup of this is driving me nuts.

For Angular, the default folder for output is `/dist`. Angular CLI does all the minification and tree-shaking you can dream of and then outputs both its JavaScript files and `index.html` to that folder.

So if I run `index.html`, those files are retrieved from the same folder. Everything works well, because `index.html` contains a tag like this one:

```
<base href="/">
```

The Web API project has the expected structure, with the Angular app a parasite in its root.

So it looks like this:

```
WebAPI_Project
|- App_Start
|    |
|    |-WebApiConfig.cs
|- Controllers
|- Models
|- src /* This is the root of the Angular app */
|    |- app
|    |    |- core           /* These three folders */
|    |    |- shared         /* are for the modules */
|    |    |- another_module /* used in the app     */
|    |    |- app.component.ts
|    |    |- app.module.ts
|    |- index.html
|- dist /* This is the Angular output folder */
     |- index.html
     |- main.bundle.js
```

`WebApiConfig.cs` has the default setup:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

To run the Angular app, I use normal `ng serve`, which create a web server at `http://localhost:4200`. This web server knows nothing about the Web API project, so I need to run that as well from within Visual Studio, which starts up IIS Express at `http://localhost:5200`.

This setup works reasonably well and allows me to take advantage of Angular CLI's live reload support.

The biggest drawback for me is that this configuration is different from what we expect for production. There, I would expect to have one web server (IIS), serving both the Web API project (at `/api/` as presently) and the Angular app (at `/`, preferably). Also, in dev, I'm having to think of CORS, which the production setup wouldn't.

To do this, I need to change the WebApiConfig routing to serve my static files, which will be under `/dist/`.

For ASP.NET Core and for MVC 4, there are numerous articles showing how I should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` (or `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles`) in `Startup.cs`. Basically, add the following two lines to the `Configure` function:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Other stuff

    // Two new lines
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();

    app.UseMvc(m =>
    {
        // Other routes specified here
    });
}
```

The problem is that I don't use either ASP.NET Core or MVC.

Despite Web API apparently being MVC without the views, a Web API project comes with only the `WebApiConfig.cs` file, no `Startup.cs` and no `IApplicationBuilder'.

I tried adding this line to my `Register` function:

```
config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("StaticFiles", "*.html");
```

This serves the index.html (but at `localhost:5200/dist/index.html`), but it cannot find any of its assets, because `base href="/"`. I can change that in `index.html`, but then `ng serve` breaks.

I think I need one of two things:

1. A way to create a route so a reference to `/index.html` serves `/dist/index.html`, or
2. A way to use the StaticFiles assembly mentioned before.

So how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just couldn't get [Dmitriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875602/127826) to work for me, but he did put me on the right track.

I needed two rules: One to serve the Angular app from the root while maintaining the Web API `/api/` routing, and another to serve the default document.

Here they are:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      <rule name="Serve Angular app from root" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="([\w\.]+)" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Default document" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I have a similar situation.  Adding this to web.config file doesn't seem to work for me.  I added this to the <system.webServer> section

Comment: This worked for me except that I deployed angular 2 files in root itself so I removed /dist from your example. Thanks.

Comment: This works when used a domain name. If we have route in the URL and paste it on the address bar it still goes for a search of an API instead of loading index.html with route parameters

Answer (score 4):

You need **first** disable web api routing for angular files, add this to web.config, inside `<system.webServer> </system.webServer>`:

```xml
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And then, add `<base href="/">` to your index.html.

UPD: Rewrite access to index.html

You can add another rewrite rule to override access to your `/dist/` folder:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="DistAccess" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)/dist/(.*)" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}/{R:3}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Great! I can now serve my Angular app from either Visual Studio or `ng serve`. Is there a way for me to rewrite it so that index.html is at `/`, not `/dist/`?

Comment: I completely dont understand what u need, if you need to access your app like `yourdomain.com/some-angular-url` you need to change rewrite action to`<action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/index.html" />`, but if you want to store your index.html out of dist folder, you need to work with your module bindler

Comment: The HTML and JS files are all under `/dist/`. I want them to be served at `/`, so if a user loads the site at `www.something.com/`, he'll be served `index.html`, which should have access to all its script files.

Comment: If you link your action to `/dist/index.html` you will get same result, but only data will be stored inside `/dist/`, but users would see `www.something.com/` as well

Comment: We're missing each other somewhere. Using your answer, I can still only access the app at `/dist/index.html`, the address bar reflects `/dist/` and the resources cannot be loaded (base href = "/"). What I want is for the address bar to display `/`, `/dist/index.html` to be served. Its JS files to be accessed using `/script.js` but actually served from `/dist/script.js`.

Comment: Then I break `ng serve`.

Comment: Uodeted your answer

Comment: This works when used a domain name. If we have route in the URL and paste it on the address bar it still goes for a search of an API instead of loading index.html with route parameters

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should publish your angular project like this below.

```
ng build --prod="true" --base-href /
```

Then add web config file to your angular project .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

notice url in  `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />` is that url in `--base-href /` .